# javascript convert or wrap object into array for complex JSON

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a JSON that looks something like this:

```
var countries = [
{
  name: 'united states',
  program: {
              name: 'usprogram'
           }
},
{
  name: 'mexico',
  program: {
              name: 'mexico program'
           }
},
{
  name: 'panama',
  program: [
             {
               name: 'panama program1'
             },
             {
               name: 'panama program2'
             }
           ]
},
{
  name: 'canada'
}
];
```

Is there a way to ALWAYS wrap the `countries.programs` object into an array such that the final output looks something like this?  I tried some of the utility functions in underscoreJS, but the solution has eluded me.

```
var countries = [
{
  name: 'united states',
  program: [    //need to wrap this object into an array
             {
              name: 'usprogram'
             }
           ]
},
{
  name: 'mexico',
  program: [   //need to wrap this object into an array
             {
               name: 'mexico program'
             }
           ]
},
{
  name: 'panama',
  program: [
             {
               name: 'panama program1'
             },
             {
               name: 'panama program2'
             }
           ]
},
{
  name: 'canada'
}
];
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you making your JSON? Or do you want to convert the member to an array only when you are accessing it?

Comment: That's not JSON, that is Javascript objects and arrays. JSON is a text format to represent objects and arrays.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not automatic, no. Loop through the countries, then `country.program = [].concat(country.program)`. This last piece of magic will wrap the value if it is not an array, and leave it as-is if it is. Mostly. (It will be a different, but equivalent array).

**EDIT per request**:

```
_.each(countries, function(country) {
  country.program = [].concat(country.program);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Could you type out how this would work?

Comment: Good call with `[].concat(...)`! That was the functionality I was searching for. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could work

```
_.each(countries, function(country) { 
          ! _.isArray(country.program) && (country.program = [country.program]);
                  });
```

Comment: This one worked for me, but JSLint throws this error:
Error:
Problem at line 24 character 79: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
! _.isArray(country.program) && (country.program = [country.program...

Comment: @Kevin: It is a style complaint; the program should still work.